# Aproval of agent created product by admin. I have a boolean field publish in product model which is false by default. Rails 5 app

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 different devise model for agent and admin then I have product model which a agent can create a new products which can be approved by admin user.

I have a boolean field publish in product model which is false by default.

Admin can also view the products.

I need to have a publish button which change the boolean value to true without reloading the page. Then the publish button changes to unpublish. How to do it with jquery or something else.

I'm new to rails and this is my first app. Need guidance..
Thank you guys..

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for two different things here.

1. Submit a change to the back-end without reloading the page.
2. Update the publish button on the front-end when the back-end change occurs.

(below code is just example code - you'll need it to fit your current setup)

I would handle this by making the "Publish" button `remote: true`. Maybe your link looks like this:

```
<%= link_to “Publish”, product_path(product_id: product.id), class: "publish", remote: true %>
```

The `remote: true` will make this an AJAX request.

In your javascript, you'll want to watch for a successful ajax request and perform some action once it's completed successfully.

```
$(‘.publish a’).on (‘ajax:success’, updatePublishBtn)

function updatePublishBtn(event, data) {
  $(‘.publish a’).text("Unpublish");
}
```

Something like this would watch for a link with a class of `publish` and would update the text to "Unpublish" when it receives a successful ajax response. In reality, you'll probably want your javascript to hide the publish button and show an unpublish button (which would work the same way) since clicking "Unpublish" should hit a different route...

This will give you the general idea, but you'll need to fill in the specifics based on your use case (or provide code in your answer so I can be more specific).

Comment: that publish button need to update the boolean value in the product model to true. The publish button should change according to the value of the boolean. Boolean=false button is publish. Boolean=true button is unpublish.    Sry for being weired. I'm very new to development

Comment: You need a controller action to hit - I'm not sure what that action is based on the information that you provided, but that's what your `link_to`'s path should be. Maybe you have a specific `products_controller#publish` action, or maybe you just want to use `products_controller#edit`. Whatever it is, make your update there, and then based on that you can either return and assume that it went well, or return the whole product object as json and update it based on that data. Your question is extremely broad, so providing more detail would help narrow things down.